# How can I make notepad++ delete everything other than the contents of the 2nd " " on every line (including the " " things) and every odd line?

Tags: notepad++, regex

for example:

```
line 1:"advancements.adventure.adventuring_time.description": "Tüm biyomları keşfet",

line 2: "advancements.adventure.adventuring_time.title": "Macera Zamanı",`
```

i want it to delete everything but `Macera Zamanı`

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't try anything since I don't know how it works.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I searched for an answer but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*\R(?:[^"]*"){3}([^"]*)".*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .*          # 0 or more any character
    \R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    (?:         # non capture  group
        [^"]*       # 0 or more any character that is not double quote
        "           # double quote
    ){3}        # end group, must appear 3 times
    ([^"]*)     # group 1, 0 or more any character that is not double quote
    "           # double quote
    .*          # 0 or more any character
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, the data between the second pair of quotes
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't delete even lines completely.

Comment: @glai: What is your expected output? Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1669704/edit) and add expected output for your example.

Comment: It was already added before your answer.

Comment: @glai: From 2 lines, you want to keep only the data between the second pair of quotes in the second line, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, It's correct.

Comment: @glai: See my edit.

Comment: @glai: May I know why you heave unaccepted my answer? Does it work or not? Please, clarify.

Comment: i made it work by using the bookmart delete function and bookmarking every line witht the word "description" and used the previous regex that you provided.